# How to write aggregate function in sql by grouping

Tags: sql, db2

My requirement is to sum up values in a particular column grouped by single column only. However, I have another set of columns in my select statement which are not to be used while summing up.

For ex:

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
    case when sum(col4) > '1000' then 'value greater than 1000'
    else col4 end as modified_col4
from table1
group by col3
```

Here I want to use SUM function by grouping only col3. But I need other columns too. While trying above query I am getting error

> "ERROR 42803 A column or expression present inn select clause missing
> in group by clause".

How to handle this? Can someone help me out here

Comment: Add an example with your table of input data and the desired result of your query.

Comment: create table employee(emp_id int, emp_name varchar(30), salary decimal(15,2))

insert into employee
values (
('111','John','1000.00'),
('222','Nick','800.00'),
('333','Ron','1100.00')
)

create table state(emp_id int, emp_name varchar(30), state(10), ratio decimal(15,5))
insert into state_info
values (
('111','John','NY','0.44444'),
('111','John','TX','0.56666'),
('222','Nick','LA','0.33333'),
('222','Nick','CT','0.67777'),
('333','Ron','NJ','0.22222'),
('333','Ron','NJ','0.78888')
)

Comment: Here my requirement is like, I want to join employee table with state_info table on emp_id and emp_name and divide the salary based on states 
by multiplying salary with the ratio of respective state and output should be rounded to 2 decimals. As ratio has 
5 decimals in state_info table after rounding if the summarized amount based on emp_id and name after allocating states 
is greater than the original amount in employee table for that particular emp_id and name then the difference amount should be 
adjusted with the state with highest amount.

Comment: Hey, not as comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want window functions:

```
select col1, col2, col3, 
       (case when sum(col4) over (partition by col3) > 1000
             then 'value greater than 1000'
             else cast(col4 as varchar(255))
        end) as modified_col4
from table1;
```

You need to be very careful about types.  Your pseudo-code has two errors:

1. You are comparing the result of a mathematical operation (`sum()`) to a string `'1000'`.  Note:  implicit conversion will hide this problem.
2. You have a `case` expression that returns different types (a string and a number).  This will return a type conversion error.